# How to write a unit test for files removed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nullreferenceexception, filenotfoundexception

I am now fixing a defect, the original code is like below:

```
public void Run()
{
    var tempOutputDir = new DirectoryInfo("d:\Test\");
    GenerateFiles(tempOutputDir);
    var result = RunToStreamCore(tempOutputDir);
}

void GenerateFiles()
{
    // Run complex logic to generate files
}

public MemoryStream RunToStreamCore(DirectoryInfo outputDir)
{
    return new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(outputDir.GetFiles()[0].FullName));
}
```

I assume the root cause of this defect may be caused by the generated file was deleted by the third party program, then outputDir.GetFiles()[0] throw null reference exception.

I am going to refactor the RunToStreamCore method like this:

```
public MemoryStream RunToStreamCore(DirectoryInfo outputDir)
{
    var files = outputDir.GetFiles();
    if (files.Length > 0)
    {
        return new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(files.First().FullName));
    }
    else
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("The file can not be found.");
    }   
}
```

The question is how to wirte a unit test for this scenario? How to simulate the behaviour of delete file before get the file?

Comment: How familiar are you with Dependency Injection?

Comment: Not very familiar, just know the concept and used for 1-2 times before.

Comment: In order to.test that scenario, the code would.need to be abstracted away from the file system interactions, so that you could simulate `GetFiles` returning a file which is deleted before use. However, if other applications are able to interact with the files, it may be better spending time altering the design of the application to avoid that. For example, here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50058630/) where an app is processing files in a folder specific to the app, and even that intermittently gets a 1-in-1,000,000 (provable statistic) error.

Comment: @JimmyWang for me at least, to test this requires Dependency Injection to abstract out the `GetFiles` method and actually the rest of the `File` methods. Overall, I'm not sure this method is really that testable.